# How to place jQuery functions in a *.js file?

Tags: jquery, dom

In the head section I embed the "jquery-X.min.js" and on the bottom (right before the closing body-tag) I embed a "bottom.js".

I want to add jQuery functions to bottom.js, but it seems only a few work there, others I have to add directly to the DOM usings a script-tag.

Working in bottom.js:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({insertAtCaret:function(a){...
```

or

```
addOnloadHook(function () {...})
```

This I need to add to the DOM:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function someFunctionName(){if($(".someClassName").height()==0){...
</script>
```

How would I add to "bottom.js"?

Edit:

I have tried this in bottom.js:

```
/* Fallback */
$(function () {
    if ($(".default").height() == 0) {
        $(".fallBack").toggle()
    }
});
```

and

```
/* Fallback */
if ($(".default").height() == 0) {
    $(".fallBack").toggle()
}
```

No luck :/

Answer (score 0):

In the head of your document put the code in a ready call.

```
$(function() {
 // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```